# Monitor switches when on lock

Tags: display

I think this is a bug.

When I put my system on lock screen, OS turns off my primary monitor, and turns on the other monitor that I disabled. When I unlock the system, normal settings turned back on. The whole thing is super awkward. You can see my display setting below

[image]

Grey monitor should be off, but it becomes primary monitor after screen is locked.

Answer (score 1):

I have a quick "workaround" that might work for you; install xscreensaver. When I lock my screen now, it uses xscreensaver instead of Pantheon's stuff and doesn't try to go to the LightDM screen, to which I don't think it's saving any personal display settings between the desktop and the greeter and is causing a lot of problems for people.